# SharePoint sandbox webpart error by required field validator

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sandbox

I have a sandbox webpart, it works fine until I add "RequiredFieldValidator" control.
It seems that only "CustomValidator" works fine.

I am getting following message:
*Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.*

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Required to set all required propoerties, for example for a RequiredFieldValidator "ControlToValidate" should be specified.
I had suspect that I should specified that before I take a look at how the html page looks like, I was in rush so ran the application and got that error.

I think the following error occurs when a control on the WebPart generates the error,this could be one of the reason:
*Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.*